# ignore "User Defined Type Not Defined" error

Tags: vba

I have a problem with an "User-defined Type Not Defined", but **I don't want** to resolve it, I want to ignore it.

**Situation:** in a word document (.docm) I use an external dll (C#, create by me, I have the control on it). This dll is use to improve control over the document (importing model parts / search depending parameters / ...). The dll define specific User Type

The custom dll is called when the user click on a button. It check if the dll is load or not. If not, it display a message like "Actions disabled"

Exemple of call:

```
' This call is from "ThisDocument"
Private Sub planAction_Click()
    ' If the dll is not load, display warning message
    If Not MqDllInstalled Then
        Call MsgBox("Actions disabled", vbInformation, "Action unavailable")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' This function is in a module
    Call FuncPlanAction
End Sub
```

it call

```
Public Sub FuncPlanAction()
    ...
    If exist Then
        ' WordElementType_PlanAction is a "User-Type Defined"
        Call GotoTable(WordElementType_PlanAction, Now)
    End If
    ...
End Sub
```

and the definition of GotoTable

```
Private Sub GotoTable(ByVal name As WordElementType, ByVal dt As Date)
```

So, if I click on the button "planAction", instead of only display the message "Actions disabled", it raise an "User Defined Type Not Defined" because it try to resolve FuncPlanAction.

**What I want:** that no error raise.

**Why not solve:** The document must be share, and if the reference is not available I just disable advanced functions.

**What I know:**

- where the problem come from: the reference is not solve so it don't find the User-Defined Type
- How the VBA compilator works: it try to load a module as soon as a call is done in it (and if this module call an other module the same happen). So until I call a module with the custome User-Type, no "User-Type" will raise.

**What I have tried:**

- I have a module separate module "LoadDll" with no User-Type defined to try to load the custom dll. If he can't find dll/tlb to load, no error raise in the loading.
- Surround the caller with a `On error goto` / `On error resume next` (in `planAction_Click` and `FuncPlanAction`)
- Put the function in a different Module

Does anyone know how to catch this error ? don't raise it ? Any other suggestions ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace this line

```
Call FuncPlanAction
```

with this

```
Call Application.Run("FuncPlanAction")
```

Comment: This answer could use a bit of commentary explaining why it works.

Comment: When you know how VBA compilator works it's logical ;) Like I explained in my problem, vba don't load a module until he find a reference to a function/sub. In my problem `Call FuncPlanAction` is resolve at compilation because it's a "static call", while `Application.Run("FuncPlanAction")` resolve the macro at runtime and not at compilation.